# PANDAS : converting int64 to string results in object dtype

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'GL': [2311000200.0, 2312000600.0, 2330800100.0]})
```

df1.dtypes is float so first I convert it to int64 to removes .0 digitals
df1.GL = df1.GL.astype('int64')

Then I try to convert it to str but instead I receive object dtype.

[image]

Does anyone know what can be the reason?

Comment: Pandas doesn't show dtype `str`. Columns of strings are always of type `object`

Comment: The issue is that when I save it as csv file it is a number, not a string

Comment: Do you need something like  `"2311000200.0"` (with `"..."`) in your csv file? or how exactly should it look like in your csv file?

Comment: Also, what program are you opening your CSV file with?

Answer (score 2):

The type `object` is actually string in pandas dataframe.

If you would like to retain the data as string, use `df.to_excel()` instead of `df.to_csv`. This is because when opening the CSV file, Excel will automatically convert the number data to numbers.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'GL': [2311000200.0, 2312000600.0, 2330800100.0]})
df1.GL = df1.GL.astype('int64').astype('string')
df1.to_excel('test.xlsx', index=False)
```

[image]

Comment: astype('int64').astype('string') worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You can force it to use the `string` dtype by using:

```
>>> df1.GL.astype("string")

df1.GL

0    2311000200.0
1    2312000600.0
2    2330800100.0
Name: GL, dtype: string
```

However, `object` dtypes are fine for most string operations. As per the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/text.html#text-types):

> For backwards-compatibility, object dtype remains the default type we infer a list of strings to